# Strength Calculation of a Simply Supported 3D rectangular beam Under Loading As Shown In Image Attached

Tags: classical-mechanics, moment-of-inertia, stress-strain, structural-beam, design

[image]For a 2D and 3D circular beam we can easily calculate the strength of beam and reactions using beam theory.

The same can be used for 2D rectangular plate.

Also for a 3D rectangular plate with uniform loading like a point load or a UDL, already equations have been derived.

But was wondering what if the beam is a simply supported rectangular beam with some random loading? Like in an image attached. Wondering how can we start?

I was thinking about drawing shear force and bending moment diagram along both length and width axis and then taking the maximum bending moment out of it and using the beam equation,
Strength = Max Bending Moment/Section Modulus to find strength of beam.

Or

Through books and google I discovered something called as Classical Plate Theory, which can easily be applied if loads are uniform but what about some random loads at random points?

I did not find any but does an alternative approach other than these exist? Or are there any corrections in these existent approach?

Attached image just for understanding the problem better, don't require a solution of corresponding values in the image.

**Summary of the question** - Which theory would be suitable for solving a problem as shown in image?

Thanking you for your time in reading this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Its my first time here, Not sure how it goes. But have refined the question title and added question summary in the question. Just need to find strength of the rectangular plate under this type of loading. (Shown in image)